# Firebase audience event count

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, audience

Firebase Audience is defined as follows:

> Once created, an audience accumulates users who meet the specified criteria from that point onward by virtue of the events that their devices log.

But I'm not sure about one fact.

1. Let's say I have user, who already did `eventA` 2 times.
2. Then I create Audience, which is defined that user needs to do `eventA` 3 times.
3. The user does event one more time (so for the 3rd in his/her lifetime but only once since the Audience creation).

Now the question is simple:
Will be the user part of audience or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once an app has been integrated with Firebase Analytics, it will keep a running total of the number of times each event has been logged on that device by that app. That's the count that's used to test event count filters. So after (3) in the original question, the user will be part of the audience.

Note: event filters are only evaluated when the event they measure is logged, so if the user had already logged your event three times before you created the audience they wouldn't be counted as part of the audience until the next time they logged the event.